# Is it possible to know the actual height of OLE object?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

I have an OLEContainer object, in which I create Word.Document, to allow to edit formulas and other.

How do I set OLEContainer height to height of actual data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OleContainer has SizeMode property than can be set to smAutoSize. Too easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a TOleContainer, once you activate MS Word in it you can easily
obtain an reference to the MS Word Automation object like this:

```
MSWord := OleContainer1.OleObject;
```

So far, so simple.

The next step is to try to get a number which represents the height of the Word document
open in the MSWord object.  The problem with that is that the structure of the document
is potentially so complex, and there are so many variables to take into account
(font size, inter-paragraph spacing etc) that I can't think of a simple way
to obtain an exact number.

However, a simple-minded way to approach the problem is to get a number for the number of lines
in the document and then scale the OleContainer's height by a multiplier of that value;  The
method below will obtain the count of the number of lines in the document (or its main text,
at any rate) and you could then adjust the container's height based on that;

```
procedure TForm1.GetLinesInDocument;
var
  Lines : Integer;
  MSWord,
  vDialog : OleVariant;
begin

  MSWord := OleContainer.OleObject;

  vDialog := MSword.Dialogs.Item(wdDialogToolsWordCount);  // this Dialog returns the number of
  //  lines in the document

  vDialog.Execute;  //  This executes the Dialog function without causing 
  //  it to display

  Lines := vDialog.Lines;
  Caption := 'Lines: ' +  IntToStr(Lines);

end;
```

Obviously some experiment would be necessary to determine the scale factor.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm posting this comment in case it catches the eye of @CindyMeister, a Word automation guru, in case she can make any suggestions